# How do I construct an ajax call randomizes images on a webpage upon refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm working on a group project and I want to be able to randomize images from a databse on a webpage with these images linking to appropriate webpages. I am a total noob to ajax and php, and I've been solely working on the front end development of this website. so far Ive been given these php methods

```
function executeZParamQuery($sql) 

{
    //executes and returns data from database
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysqli);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);

    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
    {
        $result = iimysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        $data = array();
        while ($row = iimysqli_result_fetch_array($result))
            $data[] = $row;

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        return $data;
     }

    error_log("Failed to execute prepared statement: "
    .mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
    die ("Failed to execute prepared statement: "
    .mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
}

function getAllImg()
{
    $sql = "SELECT RecipeID, PictureID FROM Pictures";

    echo json_encode(executeZParamQuery($sql));
}
```

but I have no idea how to utilise ajax to actually manipulate these functions and generate random images. Please send some guidance.

edit: thought I'd show you guys the html and where I want to link the images and links too

```
<div class="banner">
    <a href="">
    <img class="first" src="http://i.imgur.com/gZo0lXk.jpg" alt=""        style="width:350px; height: 233px;" />
    </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/o0H3If2.png" alt="" style="width:350px; height: 233px;" />
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/p1DFGse.png" alt="" style="width:350px; height: 233px;" />
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ck0dtSd.png" alt="" style="width:350px; height: 233px;" />
  </a> 
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RAHLxlm.png" alt="" style="width:350px; height: 233px;" />
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bVGK4hq.png" alt="" style="width:350px; height: 233px;" />
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gZo0lXk.jpg" alt="" style="width:350px; height: 233px;" />
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/o0H3If2.png" alt="" style="width:350px; height: 233px;" />
  </a>
   <a href=""> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/p1DFGse.png" alt="" style="width:350px; height: 233px;" />
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ck0dtSd.png" alt="" style="width:350px; height: 233px;" />
  <a href="">
  </div>
```

the last 4 images are the same as the first 4 as I have an animated moving banner.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you don't need Ajax to return you random, in the SQL statement itself you can actually get the random images.

```
function getAllImg()
{
    $sql = "SELECT RecipeID, PictureID FROM Pictures ORDER BY RAND() ";

    echo json_encode(executeZParamQuery($sql));
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea how i'd actually implement it on a webpage though. Thank you.

Comment: As in how I'd incorporate this function with HTML to change th images